# How to call moodle function

Tags: moodle

I'm testing moodle function (core_user_create_users) via SoapUI. Every time i call the function via url that i have designed. i gets error of invalid parameter

https://localhost/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=90b089f55f481a7d6b534bbe2b848203&wsfunction=core_user_create_users&moodlewsrestformat=json&users[0][username]=ayubjamal[0][password]=li@mR0cks!&users[0][firstname]=Ayub&users[0][lastname]=Jamal&users[0][email]=ajamal@mailinator.com

I expect the output to be the JSON Response as shown
{
"id": 2,
"username": "ayubjamal"
}

Comment: can any one help whats wrong in the url

Comment: Missing a &users after your username

    `&users[0][username]=ayubjamal---->&users<------[0][password]=li@mR0cks!&users[0] . 
    [firstname]=Ayub&users[0][lastname]=Jamal&users[0] . 
    [email]=ajamal@mailinator.com`